# limit the height in videojs in fluid mode

Tags: javascript, css, video.js, videojs-transcript

I am working with videojs and set **fluid:true**
It covers the full width, which is exactly what I wanted.
Now the issue is **it changes height of player**, and it is different for different videos. I want it to be maximum 500px.
[Here](http://stashad.com/fahad-client/app/09-watch.php?videoId=33&channelId=2) you can check it live what I have done.

Comment: can you not just set a `max-height` of 500px?

Comment: I tried, its not working. I guess fluid:true overrides it.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem. Our video was already pretty customized, so these rules may not be enough for you, but here's what I did. It's super hacky, due to needing to override CSS:

```
/* Make the video relative, instead of absolute, so that
   the parent container will size based on the video. Also,
   note the max-height rule. Note the line-height 0 is to prevent
   a small artifact on the bottom of the video.
 */
.video-js.vjs-fluid,
.video-js.vjs-16-9,
.video-js.vjs-4-3,
video.video-js,
video.vjs-tech {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  position: relative !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Fix the control bar due to us resetting the line-height on the video-js */
.vjs-control-bar {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Personnally I lose the ratio of the image video with this solution :(

Comment: This works perfectly still except for I had to remove the comma at the end of `video.vjs-tech` when I put it in my CSS. Not sure if that's just me using standard CSS though. Otherwise works great and doesn't stretch the video content or anything weird like that.

Comment: FYI I had the same experience as @ToddRylaarsdam so I edited the code block in the answer to remove the extraneous comma. Assuming that edit isn't reverted Todd's comment _was_ accurate but that comma has been removed. Noting this change just in case anyone is confused.